# Why doesn't node/nest finds a module in the src folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

sO I have this NestJs project.

I want to debug a module I'm using (node-os-tools). So I pasted it from node_modules inside the src dir and instead I using the usual `import * as osutils from 'node-os-utils` I used
`import * as osutils from './node-os-utils`

I didn't work. I got this error:

```
my_api | Error: Cannot find module './node-os-utils'
my_api | Require stack:
my_api | - /api/dist/src/app.service.js
my_api | - /api/dist/src/app.controller.js
my_api | - /api/dist/src/app.module.js
my_api | - /api/dist/src/main.js
my_api |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
my_api |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
my_api |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
my_api |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
my_api |     at Object.<anonymous> (/api/src/app.service.ts:6:1)
my_api |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
my_api |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
my_api |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
my_api |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
my_api |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
```

Anyone knows why is that. It's the exact same file structure. Why can't I just import a module this way ?

Answer (score 0):

Because Typscript wasn't incluing it in the compilation. I just included

```
"allowJs": true,
```

in tsconfig.json compilerOptions and that was it.